# Flush cache in Laravel 5.2 on shared hosting without SSH?

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching, mod-rewrite, laravel-5

2 questions actually:

1. How do I setup a Laravel site in a subfolder?
2. How do I flush/clear the cache?

My current situation:

I'm on shared hosting (don't mock me....I know dedicated server is better....trying to figure out how much budget to allocate for it so currently using shared since I can pay monthly) and can't use SSH.

URL structure is like this: website.com/v2 where "v2" is the subfolder where the site is installed on.

Is this the way my .htaccess and index.php are supposed to be setup?

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /v2/

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

index.php

```
require __DIR__.'/../v2/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../v2/bootstrap/app.php';
```

For clearing the cache, I got this code in routes.php:

```
Route::get('/v2/configcache', function() {
$exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
print_r($exitCode);
});
```

Are all of the codes above setup correctly?  When I go to mywebsite.com/v2/configcache, I get an "Under Construction" message.

I need to clear the cache because I updated the database info.

Comment: //I need to clear the cache because I updated the database info.//
Are you running application using php artisan serve?